# automatic script writing from a audio/video?

Tags: video, audio

Is there some software for generating scripts from audios or videos of recordings in English, such as those in Youtube, NewYorkTimes, ...? Free or Open Source software and software under Ubuntu are preferred. Thanks!

Comment: What "scripts"? Do you mean speech to text?

Comment: Yes, @Karan. ...

Answer (score 1):

There are a few open-source speech recognition projects, although this is not a perfected technology.

If you need accurate results manual transcribing is the only option.

[List of Open Source Speech Recognition Software](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_speech_recognition_software#Open_Source)